# Como publicar um site MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Fiz uma assinatura de hospedagem no Godaddy e estou com dúvida pra publicar o projeto.

Atualmente no diretório raiz do site contém apenas uma pagina HTML: index.html, como podemos ver abaixo.

**index.html**:
[image]

A dúvida começa quando inicio a publicação do site:

**Publish - VS 2013**

Tenho certeza de que não vou publicar no AZURE;
Não vou fazer uma importação;
Então vou fazer uma publicação Custon:

[image]

Aqui em **Publish Method** não sei com certeza qual opção devo selecionar, eu imagino que seja **File System**

[image]

**File System**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E por fim esses arquivos são gerados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para o projeto (site publicado) iniciar na página index do projeto publicado (projeto MVC 5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu tenho exatamente sua infra estrutura. Configura como FTP.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logico que para o www.meusite.com.br responder no index você tem que configurar, o que é uma configuração padrão... por isso acredito que não tenha problema.

Com essa configuração ele vai jogar o site pronto para dentro do seu httpdocs.